# React Native 0.70.7 Autofill Account Management

Tags: android, ios, react-native, autofill, password-autofill

I am triying to activate autofill for both iOS and Android for account management forms and I can not simply make it work consistently.

I already have the iOS entitlement set up, so autofill somewhat works.

My use cases are as follows:

## Login

One email (autoComplete=username, importantForAutofill=yes only on android; textContentType=username only on iOS) field and one password field (autoComplete=password, importantForAutofill=yes only on android; textContentType=password only on iOS with secureTextEntry on both).

### iOS

This one seems to work fine on iOS. You can autofill with account. If you then change password, it asks if you want to update. If you log in with new account, it asks if you want to register it. It has the minor problem that it asks even if you don't log in (if you go to register page instead after filling the form).

### Android

On android it also seems to work, at least the autofill part, but then it never or almost never asks to register account if it is new nor it asks to update if you change the password after filling it.

## Simple Forms with just 1 username or 1 password field

In case of forgot password form (1 username field) or destroy account form (1 password field) eveything seems to work fine because they are not complex enough.

## Create account form

One email (autoComplete=username-new, importantForAutofill=yes only on android; textContentType=username only on iOS) field and two password field (autoComplete=password-new, importantForAutofill=yes only on android; textContentType=newPassword only on iOS with secureTextEntry on both). There are 2 password fields for new password and password confirmation.

### iOS

This one seems to work fine on iOS. I think i had a problems with putting 2 newPassword fields. I don't remember if the first one was left as just password instead of newPassword. One thing I definetly saw is that when you touch password inputs after filling the username, it asks you if you want to generate strong password. If you decline and fill it manually, when you finishing registering and manage to enter the app, the device asks if you want to save it, which is great. If you choose to genereate strong password, it saves the account without asking before you can send the form. Just a minor problem, I don't really know if there is way to solve this.

### Android

This one seems to work fine too, but when it asks you to generate strong password, the generate strong password system popup does not contain the username introduced into the form.

## Update password form

One password field (autoComplete=password, importantForAutofill=yes only on android; textContentType=password only on iOS with secureTextEntry on both).

Then one email hidden (1 pixel x 1 pixel) field (autoComplete=username-new, importantForAutofill=yes only on android; textContentType=username only on iOS).

Then two password fields (autoComplete=password-new, importantForAutofill=yes only on android; textContentType=newPassword only on iOS with secureTextEntry on both). There are 2 password fields for new password and password confirmation.

### iOS

This one seems to work fine on iOS apart from the other already mentioned problems in previous forms.

### Android

This one does not work. It autofills and it asks for strong password but never ask me to update password in keychain.

## General Android Problems

I swear to God that Android randomly stops autofilling and randomly asks you if you want to store account when you return to the phone after unlocking it after leaving the app for a while instead of asking when it has to do it.